# SQL string search: indexing one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to search for particular strings. So instead of putting the keyword on the string itself (ex. `select *  from report r where Upper (r.summary) like '%FRANK%'`) , I saved all the words on a table. Now how do you index that keyword table.

Example:
`'Frank'` is added to "Keywordtable", now I want to see any on the "Report" summary table with the mention of that keyword, "Frank". Is it possible to do?

**Just to be more clear**

```
select *
from contact_document r
where Upper (r.summary) like '%CANCER%'
```

but the keywords are saved on a table with the list of diseases, called "diseasetable"

```
select m.disease, m.rowid 
from diseasetable m
```

I wanted to every time i run the script, it will return any `contact_document` with any of the diseases listed on the `diseasetable` appearing on `r.summary`

Comment: Seems to be straightforward. As the solution suggested by @shA.t still didn't work: Could you possibly provide some sample rows from both tables?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    yourTableOfStrings s
  JOIN
    yourTableOfKeywords k
  ON s.string Like CONCAT('%', k.keyword, '%');
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cfe3/1)

Comment: i tried this   
select *
from contact_document r
join diseasetable  s
on r.summary  like '%' + s.disease + '%'  it didn't run because of error.

i tried   
select *
from contact_document r
join diseasetable  s
on r.summary  like '%s.disease%'
it yielded nothing.

Comment: @user3139937 What was the error message for the first query? Second query treats **s.disease** as literal string to be found in **r.summary** rather than as a column name. (Thus no error - but an empty result.)

Comment: I get ORA-01722 invalid number

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server ?

Comment: Right: Oracle does string concatenation like this `'%' || s.disease || '%'` or `CONCAT(CONCAT('%', k.keyword), '%')`. An alternative: join on `INSTR(s.string, k.keyword) > 0`.